# Selenium - Python - Get Captcha Url ( from generated link )

Tags: django, selenium, captcha, urllib2

Python - Selenium / urllib2

I need to get the url to download a captcha image.

Image code : img src = "generatedlink"

I need to parse this "generatedlink" into a variable

variable = "generatedlink"

Is there a way to get this with selenium or urllib2 ?

( I am able to transfer my generated link into local.jpg file with urllib.retrieve (manually) but i cant do the first step ( get the link automatically and put it into variable) .)

Thank you for any info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using selenium 2 this is how you would do it, this example references it by xpath:

```
wd = self.webdriver
src = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='recaptcha_image']/img").get_attribute('src')
```

Comment: Thank you , its working :) is there a way with selenium to download the image inside the img src recaptcha ? Thank you again

Comment: I would do what you were talking about in the initial question and use the urllib2 like this `urllib2.Request([imgsrc])` However what do you want to do with the image?

Comment: yes i do that finally :             src = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='captcha_image']/img").get_attribute('src')
            print src

            image = urllib.URLopener()
            image.retrieve(src, "woublabla.jpg")Thanks everybody for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Python, the following should do:

```
# Assuming "sel" is your selenium instance
img_src = sel.get_attribute('css=img#myimage@src')
# Or, if you subclassed SeleniumLibrary
img_src = self._selenium.get_attribute('css=img#myimage@src')
```

Comment: I dont know why but this object doesnt work , whats is the #myimage ??cause i try this too url = driver.get_attribute("//*[contains(@src=\'recaptcha_image')]/src") and it doesnt work

Comment: i have see some post that get_attribute is not working well on python, if you have a tips thank you :)

Comment: i have try this with xpath too : img_src = driver.get_attribute("//div[@id='recaptcha_image']/img")     but doesnt work too

Comment: @AdamBovien: I forgot the css prefix, my bad. The above code works for me. When using XPath, you should also prefix your locators, but then with xpath=//expression. The `#myimage` was the object's ID... used to identify the image you are querying. You should adopt that to the ID you're using.

Comment: But the img src is in a div .... look the example please <div id="captcha" class="captcha_image" style="width: 200px; height: 58px;">
<img width="200" height="58" src="http://www.test.com/captcha/test/picture?c=03AHJ_Vuu5d7aBkgApJHP1WF_3n2tCWyKp1rVvIJ-Vc_3vOwElm5SPLIv7cJFI5JU7bIng3xpAcNhKfV_xlaIxnIsStwoN-xm3JZwiMVv8WYp5QNbbSsYS4TzTP1XHj1BKYPLyamMXy7TU5U0AHhpbJHUdpUFQ-8gkXMUl4P8fdDyx5__Mz5A9bTilT-6pP4Pfrhp5LCSA0gwX" style="...">
</div>

Comment: Then `css=div#captcha > img@src` should work for you as the locator for the `get_attribute` function.

Comment: but if you go on python doc : http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py  , there is no function call get_attribute  ...

Comment: are you shure you use python ? and what version of selenium , i use the webdriver one 2.11. Thanks again for your time

Comment: @AdamBovien: I see now that you're using WebDriver; for some reason I was assuming you were using Selenium-RC. My example works as port of a library for that...

Comment: No problem, my bad i wasnt clear on this point :) Thanks again